# Getting Blade to work with Meteor on Windows 8

Tags: node.js, windows-8, meteor, node-blade

I installed Meteor for Windows via [this MSI installer](http://win.meteor.com/). Now I would like to get Blade working with it. I read through [this tutorial](https://github.com/bminer/node-blade/wiki/Using-Blade-with-Meteor) in the Blade docs, but atmosphere/meteorite doesn't seem to work with Windows.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got meteor working? There is a manual way, ive not tried it before but it should work.

Install the blade module with npm `npm install blade`.

Clone the blade git repo and place the `meteor` subdirectory in meteors package directory, rename it to `blade` ( I think its `C:\Program Files\Meteor\packages` (but you'd have to check that directory)

Edit the files in the files in the blade directory to reference the files in the blade npm module correctly. In linux/unix this bit is easy because you could just symlink directly it into packages without copying the folders in and re referencing the files.

Finally go to your meteor project and run `meteor add blade` and it should be good to go.

Comment: Huzzah! Looks like that actually worked. Specifically, I had to change this line in `package.js` from `blade = require('../../packages/blade/node_modules/blade');` to `blade = require('C:/Users/Mark/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/blade');`

Comment: Nope..not true. The package adds, but it crashes as soon as you run Meteor. It's looking for Meteor/packages/blade/runtime.js which never came in the blade npm module.

Comment: Ok, I was poking around for `runtime.js` and I found it in `C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\blade\lib`, so I copied the entire contents of that directory into the meteor one since that's where it seems to be looking, and it seems to be running now.

Comment: did you get it to work? I was poking round `Meteor._def_template` to check blade's templating system replaces it

Comment: Just now I did, yes. Took me awhile to realize I was naming my files with the `.jade` extension instead of `.blade`. It's loading my templates nicely now.